# Display now includes inactive timestamps as well

Tags: org-agenda

I am using emacs 29.1
When going to org-agenda and then want to change to the next week ], instead of going to the next week, I get the message:

```
Display now includes inactive timestamps as well.
```

Why is that happening? I do not need this message, I need the next week of my org agenda to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I was using ] to get further in the agenda, which is right in doom emacs, but in vanilla emacs it is f.

Comment: `C-h k` is your friend.